# How can I add HTML to Form of Laravel?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

Here is my form in the Laravel:

```
{!! Form::open($user_id,['method'=>'PATCH','action'=>['changePasswordController@change',$user_id]]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('current_password',"current password:") !!}
        {!! Form::input('password', 'current_password', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('new_password',"new password:") !!}
        {!! Form::input('password', 'new_password', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('re_new_password',"re-new password") !!}
        {!! Form::input('password', 're_new_password', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    @include('errors.list')

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Now I want to add this HTML in the beginning of those labels:

```
// which says filling this field is mandatory 
<span style="color:red">*</span>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You could always use CSS label:before pseudo element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that is to put CSS into the CSS file and use class. Then simply add HTML after the label:

```
{!! Form::label('current_password',"current password:") !!}
<span class="red">*</span>
{!! Form::input('password', 'current_password', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```